# Let $I$ be an ideal generated by a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$. When is $\mathbb Q[x] / I$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I was looking at my old exam papers and I was stuck on the following problem:

> Let $I_1$ be the ideal generated by $x^4+3x^2+2$ and $I_2$ be the ideal generated by $x^3+1$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$. If $F_1=\mathbb Q[x]/I_1$ and $F_2=\mathbb Q[x]/I_2$, then which of the following options is/are  correct?
>
> 1) $F_1$ and $F_2$ are fields
>
> 2) $F_1$ is a field but $F_2$ is not a field
>
> 3) $F_2$ is a field but $F_1$ is not a field
>
> 4) neither $F_1$ nor $F_2$ is a field

Can someone explains in details how to tackle this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key points here are:

- Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field, $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a Euclidean domain.
- In a principal ideal domain, a nonzero prime ideal is maximal.
- $R / I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal (where $R$ is any commutative ring and $I$ an ideal in $R$).
- In a unique factorization domain, an element is prime iff it's irreducible.

Using these points, we find that $Q[x]/I_j$ is a field iff $I_j$ is irreducible.

$x^3 + 1$ is clearly reducible since it has a root ($x = -1$).

By the rational roots theorem, $x^4 + 3x^2 + 2$ doesn't have roots in $\mathbb Q$, but it may be factored into two polynomials of degree $2$. Write $x^4 + 3x^2 + 2 = (x^2 + ax +b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ and solve for $a, b, c, d$ to see if this is the case. Solving this can be simplified by noting that the coefficients of $x^4 + 3x^2 + 2$ are integers. By [Gauss's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29), if it's irreducible over $\mathbb Z$, it's also irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: In a non-field domain, $\,0\,$ is a prime ideal that is not maximal.

Comment: @BillDubuque Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially about asking if the polynomials are irreducible or not. For instance, for $I_2$ you can see that it has $-1$ as a root, so certainly isn't irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ \color{#c00}{x\!-\!(-1)}\mid x^3\!-(-1)^3\ $ and $\ x^4\!+3x^2\!+2 = (\color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!2})(x^2\!+\!1),\,$ or $\,(x^2\!+\!2)^2\!-(x^2\!+\!2).\ $ Hence both quotient rings have zero-divisors, $\ \color{#c00}{x\!+\!1},\ $ and $\ \color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!2},\,$ so neither is a field.

Comment: I have one question.
 Even though  $( x^4\!+3x^2\!+2)$ can be factored into $(x^2\!+\!2)$ and $(x^2\!+\!1)$,but they have no roots in $\Bbb Q[x]$ .So Is $( x^4\!+3x^2\!+2)$  irreducible ?

Comment: Yes, generally an element $f\ne 0$ of a ring is defined to be irreducible if it is not a unit (i.e. not invertible), and if $f = gh$ then $g$ or $h$ is a unit (i.e. invertible) .

Comment: I still have one confusion..You say  "if $f=gh$ then $g$ or $h$ is a unit (i.e. invertible)"..So we  have  $( x^4\!+3x^2\!+2)=(x^2\!+\!2)(x^2\!+\!1)$ ,then either $(x^2\!+\!2)$ or $(x^2\!+\!1)$ is unit and that means they are reducible. Hence ,keeping in mind that "$Q[x]/I_j$ is a field iff $I_j$ is irreducible," we can say $F_1$ and  $\,\,F_2$ is not a field.Am I right in my conclusion?